# Putting two array strings together

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```js
const template = {
      example: {
          simple: ['Hey', 'Origami'],
          extra: ['Its me', 'Dotcom']
      }
}
```

I want to join each element of template.example.simple & template.example.extra together.

So the results would be:

`['Hey', 'Origami', 'Hey Its me', 'Hey Dotcom', 'Origami Its me', 'Origami Dotcom']`

In order to accomplish that, what I'm doing right now is:

```js
const template = {
      example: {
          simple: ['Hey', 'Origami'],
          extra: ['Its me', 'Dotcom']
      }
}
const example = template.example.simple;

template.example.simple.forEach((s) => {
     let extra = s;
     template.example.extra.forEach((a) => {
         extra += ` ${a}`;
         example.push(extra);
         extra = s;
     });
});

console.log(example);
//example = ['Hey', 'Origami', 'Hey Its me', 'Hey Dotcom', 'Origami Its me', 'Origami Dotcom']
```

So my question is if there's a simpler method of accomplishing this, and how would you improve this?

Comment: Your method is actually pretty simple and therefore easily maintainable. What would you improve and why? Also, this question is for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than Stackoverflow

Comment: I would not recommend altering the original data ( `template.example.simple`) since it might have unwanted side effects in other parts of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler is a very relative term. I would not call this method simpler/easier to read, but for the sake of giving alternatives, this one liner should do the trick. It uses map to select both the original value from `simple` and an extra map to get `simple` and `extra` together (and the spread operator `...` to flatten them)

```js
const template = {
      example: {
          simple: ['Hey', 'Origami'],
          extra: ['Its me', 'Dotcom']
      }
};

const example = Array.prototype.concat(...template.example.simple.map(p=>[p,...template.example.extra.map(e=>p + ' ' + e)]));

console.log(example);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.prototype.concat()` to merge two lists into one.

On your code, it should look something similar to:

```
const newValues = template.example.simple.concat(template.example.extra);
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) you can find the documentation and different usage examples.

Comment: Although I agree with your suggestion, it would just put the 2 separate arrays together and not handle the specific use case where `extra` is not added as is, but as the result of concatenating the strings of the 2 arrays.

Comment: @Me.Name yes, I provided him the answer of what he asked, title and question from the post. He can then use the provided information to manage his specific use case from the code snippet.